# Bathroom exaust fan replacement

Tags: plumbing, hvac

My bathroom exaust fan was missing. Just the housing remained. I purchased a cheap fan and housing (Broan). After ripping the old housing out i discovered the new housing is not set up the same. Vent outlet and the mounting tabs are are on the incorrect side so cannot mount to exising joist in the attic. I have access to attic. But cannot figure out how to rectify the situation.  My issue is the actual mounting part. I can move the ductwork and electrical is easy. I just dont know how to mount the housing securely [image]

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Is the duct rigid? Do you not know how to do basic carpentry? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: There are many manufacturers (and many models from each manufacturer) of bath exhaust fans, no two will have identical housing. You should resign yourself to the fact that you will need to alter the hole in your ceiling if you want to use the new fan unit. This may entail duct and wiring modification, along with plaster/drywall patching.

Comment: There are some Broan replacement kits available for some of their standardized models. Check Big Orange, where you'll find some in stock. Take careful measurements of your housing and look for stamped model numbers for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is mounting the fan, you can add a 2x4 or 2x6 (whichever matches your joists) perpendicular to your joists and attached to them in the attic. Like building part of a plenum box. Then attach the fan to that. Basic carpentry. I like GRK fasteners but any good screws (or even nails) will do. If you want it stronger you can use brackets but that's probably excessive for something as light as a fan.

Another alternative is to get one of the Panasonic fans that comes with a mounting bracket that spans the gap between joists on the attic side and lets you position the fan as needed. Cost is higher but hassle is less, and they are good fans. I know from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one of these [self locking hanging bars](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Westinghouse-01100-Westinghouse-01100-Saf-T-Fan-Brace/21903872?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1148&adid=22222222228015827231&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=m&wl3=51753680711&wl4=pla-83153851031&wl5=9032536&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=112562587&wl11=online&wl12=21903872&wl13=&veh=sem)?

Comment: I don't think those brackets will work on the type of fan the OP is referring to, although it should give him some ideas about how he may be able to adapt to his situation with a bit of ingenuity and ambition.